# How to configure Azure Alert for Azure Functions Health Check

Tags: azure-functions, azure-alerts

I have successfully configured Health check for Azure Functions.
Next I would like to create Azure Alert and then send message with LogicApps.

How do I configure Azure Alert so that if health is not Action is taking place?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/monitor-instances-health-check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an alert based on the metrics of your Function App [http errors, failure rate, etc] using App Insights, the alert action can be configured to email you or send voice call etc. Refer http://www.mattruma.com/adventures-with-azure-functions-create-an-alert-from-app-insight-to-send-an-email-notification/ , https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/monitor-functions